# kGAIUserId shows Undefined USER-ID on google Analytics,

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I want GA for userID, bellow is my code. but when I check on Google Analytic. Its now showing the   userID, its shows Undefined USER-ID. I don't have too much idea about Google Analytic.

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIUserId value:[SharedData getUserID]]; // [SharedData getUserID] return my user ID
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

[image]